# How to force libtool to install 64-bit libraries for libffi in /lib instead of /lib64

Tags: libtool, libffi

I'm trying to compile libffi 64-bit in a SLES-11 docker container.

The configure & make lines are dead simple:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/<prog>/ --libdir=/opt/<prog>/lib
make 
make install
```

Now libtool in its glory decides to install the .so's like this:

```
/opt/<prog>/lib/../lib64/libffi.so
```

Whats the magic trick to get rid of the ../lib64 part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.

Libtool isn't the problem.

The magic in libffi's configure is. It tries to be smart and invokes 'gcc --print-multi-os-directory' and stuffs that into toolexeclibdir.

Seems that madness is commonly patched out of the configure script, for example with something like this:
https://github.com/chef/omnibus-software/blob/master/config/patches/libffi/libffi-3.2.1-disable-multi-os-directory.patch

Answer (score 1):

The following configure command works for me:

```
configure --prefix=$PREFIX --libdir=$PREFIX/lib --disable-multi-os-directory
```

Comment: Giving more details and explanations maybe references always better.

Comment: The question was about magic trick which is to disable multi-os-directory in this case. ../lib64 is coming from gcc --print-multi-os-directory command that can be disabled from the command line. It looks a little strange that it is enabled by default.